# JNI_CreateJavaVM fails from windows service

Tags: java, windows, service, windows-services, java-native-interface

When I run my code from console it works fine: the jvm gets created and runs my application. However, if I run the executable as a windows service JNI_CreateJavaVM fails and returns -1.
Do I need to configure something in my service for it to work?

Thanks

Edit: Adding code examples

I downloaded Microsoft's service example and modified it to my needs. Basically when the service starts it runs this function in a new thread:

```
void CWSMService::ServiceWorkerThread(void)
{
    // Periodically check if the service is stopping.
    wchar_t szMessage[260];
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    JavaVM *vm = NULL; 
    while (!m_fStopping)
    {        
        jint res;
        jclass cls;
        jmethodID mid;

        res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void**)&env, getVMArgs());
        if(res < 0)
        {

            StringCchPrintf(szMessage, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage), L"Can't create Java VM (%d)", res);
            WriteEventLogEntry(szMessage, EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE); 
            break;
        }
        cls = env->FindClass(JAVA_BOOTSTRAP_CLASS);
        if (cls == NULL)
        {
            StringCchPrintf(szMessage, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage), L"Class not found %s", JAVA_BOOTSTRAP_CLASS_WIDE);
            WriteEventLogEntry(szMessage, EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE);                     
            vm->DestroyJavaVM();            
            break;
        }
        mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        if (mid == 0)
        {
            StringCchPrintf(szMessage, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage), L"No main() method in class %s", JAVA_BOOTSTRAP_CLASS_WIDE);
            WriteEventLogEntry(szMessage, EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE); 
            vm->DestroyJavaVM();
            break;
        }
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, getProgramArgs(env));        
        jthrowable exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
        if (exc)
        {
            jboolean isCopy = false;
            jmethodID toString = env->GetMethodID(env->FindClass("java/lang/Object"), "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
            jstring s = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(exc, toString);
            const char* utf = env->GetStringUTFChars(s, &isCopy);
            StringCchPrintf(szMessage, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage), L"Java Exception: %s", utf);
            WriteEventLogEntry(szMessage, EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE); 
            env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(s,utf);
            vm->DestroyJavaVM();
            break;
        }

    }

    if (vm) vm->DestroyJavaVM();    
    // Signal the stopped event.
    SetEvent(m_hStoppedEvent);
    Stop();
}


JavaVMInitArgs* CWSMService::getVMArgs()
{   
    JavaVMInitArgs* vm_args = new JavaVMInitArgs(); 
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=E:\\build_0670_19_00\\jar\\Itamar.jar";
    vm_args->version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    vm_args->options = options;
    vm_args->nOptions = 1;
    vm_args->ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
    return vm_args;
}
```

When I run this executable from a Windows Service (running by either my user \ Local Service) I get this error in the event log:

> Can't create Java VM (-1)

but when I run it from command line it succeeds and runs the java code.
I tried compiling it in 32 bit mode with 32 bit java and in 64 bit mode with 64 bit java and the behaviour stays the same.

Edit 2:
It's Working!!
Some notes for future folks who may have similar issues in the future:
1. When you look up a class (let's say **com.mysite.foo.bar**) you should actually call this:
    cls = env->FindClass("com/mysite/foo/bar");
2. in classpath you can use double '\' like: **C:\\com\\mysite\\foo\\bar** or just **/C:/com/mysite/foo/bar**

In my case, it actually did create the JVM but since the service is in a while loop it failed on the second time. It didn't bothered me at the beginning since my java program shouldn't return at all but in my tests I used a program that only prints to screen... :/

Comment: You should give more details (minimal code showing the problem, for example)

Comment: Did you check if the "e:\build_0670_19_00" directory is accessible form your service?